# why can't i overwrite style of a div?

Tags: html, css

in my code i have a container with display flex,and i trageted the divs inside the container and did some styling on them.but when i try to overwrite theose styles for a specific div,it doesen't work.how can i fix this?

```css
main {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.container {
  width: 75%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 50px;
}

.container div {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #aaddaa;
  border-radius: 1rem;
}

.lanscape {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="img lanscape -L1">-L1</div>
    <div class="img lanscape -L2">-L2</div>
    <div class="img lanscape -L3">-L3</div>
    <div class="img portrait -P1"></div>
    <div class="img portrait -P2"></div>
    <div class="video landscape VL-1"></div>
    <div class="video portrait VP-1"></div>
    <div class="video portrait VP-2"></div>
    <div class="text T-1"></div>
    <div class="text T-2"></div>
    <div class="text T-3"></div>

  </div>

</main>
```

Comment: ["it doesen't work" isn't a useful description of the problem](https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/). What behaviour do you expect? What behaviour do you observer? What is the difference? What efforts have you made to debug the problem (the element inspector of the browser's developer tools is very useful for seeing which styles apply to which elements and in which order).

Comment: explain: `doesn't work`. WQhat does not work as intended? What have you tried?

Comment: it has the same styling though?

Comment: "i try to overwrite theose styles for a specific div," — Are you talking about the `.lanscape` ruleset? That targets multiple divs, not a specific one, and tries to set the styles to be identical to the ones set in the only other ruleset that targets them.

Comment: Do some reading on "CSS specificity". `.container div` has higher specificity than `.landscape`, so its styles will prevail.

Comment: @ralph.m where do you get the specificity wiegth issue from? with the same width and height I see no specificity weight issue here. The only thing that you could argue for is, that the background-color and the border should not be applied. That, however, can not be solved at specificity level either.

Comment: @tacoshy — I just figured the OP hadn't posted a proper demo and that specificity was the issue, as proved to be the case from the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write more specific styles, such as `.container div.lanscape` instead of `.landscape` since that is not more specific than `.container div`

```css
main {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.container {
  width: 75%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 50px;
}

.container div {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #aaddaa;
  border-radius: 1rem;
}

.container div.lanscape {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="img lanscape -L1">-L1</div>
  <div class="img lanscape -L2">-L2</div>
  <div class="img lanscape -L3">-L3</div>
  <div class="img portrait -P1"></div>
  <div class="img portrait -P2"></div>
  <div class="video landscape VL-1"></div>
  <div class="video portrait VP-1"></div>
  <div class="video portrait VP-2"></div>
  <div class="text T-1"></div>
  <div class="text T-2"></div>
  <div class="text T-3"></div>

</div>
```